# Emails Arrive elsewhere!

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite

I have switched over to Google Apps so that I can make use of Google's mail server. Everything is working fine. When an email is sent from any email account it arrives in my Google account.

However, whenever a user uses my site to send an email to me; I make use of PHP to send the mail. The mail arrives in my old inbox (squirrelmail) which is installed on the server. It doesn't seem to go outside of the server network, its probably looking at something listed within the server.

My domains DNS settings are elsewhere and not on the server.

I have sendmail installed and I think qmail is acting as a wrapper because of Plesk. I have removed Plesk since then.

I hope somebody has made sense of the above and can help!

Thanks all for any help on this

### Update

Cento OS (2.6.18-194.11.3.el5xen)

sendmail-8.13.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` you probably have a line like `LOCAL_DOMAIN(´yourdomain.net')dnl`. Get rid of if, recompile your config and restart sendmail.

This line tells sendmail to accept mail for this domain. Without it it looks for the MX for this domain and submits it.

Maybe you have still the "default" `sendmail.mc` of your installation, which should only be for sending mails out. Use this.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly need to reconfigure your mail server to not accept mail for your domain. Or you may be able to change your PHP scripts to use Google as the SMTP server.

If your server is setup to accept email for that domain, then the messages will be accepted and not forwarded.  You may need to include more details about your server setup (OS, mail server versions) for someone familiar with sendmail or qmail to tell you how to adjust the mail server configuration.

Comment: I have updated my question with that information.

Comment: I can't help much with sendmail.  My preferred *nix mail server is Exim.